# On the dual of AB5 condition

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I have known the following definition:

> **AB5 condition**: The abelian category is cocomplete and the small filtered colimit is exact.
> **AB5* condition**: The abelian category is complete and the small cofiltered limit is exact.

The two concepts can be dualized to each other well.

But in Page 427 of Weibel's homological algebra book, he says:

> **1**. For a cocomplete abelian category, the AB5 condition is equivalent to $\sum(A_i\cap B)=B\cap (\sum A_i)$, where $A_i$ is a lattice of subobjects of an object $A$ and $B$ is any subobject of $A$.
> **2**. For a complete abelian category, the AB5* condition is equivalent to $\cap(A_i+ B)=B+ (\cap A_i)$, where $A_i$ is a lattice of subobjects of an object $A$ and $B$ is any subobject of $A$.

My question is: Is **2** the dual satement of **1**?

By putting **1** into the opposite category, I can only dualize **1** to a statement about the quotient object. Can somebody help me?

**EDIT:** By Martin Brandenburg's comment, the above question has been solved.

In N. Popsescu's Abelian Categories with Applications to Rings and Modules (Page 55), he proves that:

> For a cocomplete abelian category, the AB5 condition is equivalent to that for any directed family of suboject $(A_j)_{j\in I}$ of $A$, $\text{Colim}_j A_j\cong \sum_j A_j$ (canonically).

I'm wondering that whether this can be dualized to the following:

> For a complete abelian category, the AB5* condition is equivalent to that for any inverse family of suboject $(A_j)_{j\in I}$ of $A$, $\text{Lim}_j A_j\cong \cap_j A_j$ (canonically).

It seems to me that the colimits of subojects and limits of quotient objects do not behave well under the correspondence $B\to A\to A/B$.

Comment: Hint: the lattice of subobjects of A is isomorphic to the lattice of quotients of A by mapping B to A/B.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The hint solves my question. Then both AB5 and AB5* conditions can be stated via conditions on subobjects/quotient objects!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I have one more question, and I have edited the original post. Could you give me more hint?

Answer (score 0):

After several days' thinking, I realize that $\text{Lim}_j A_j\cong \cap_j A_j$ (cofiltered limit) is always true in any complete abelian category. And this condition cannot be used to characterize the AB5* condition.

> **Lemma**  (Motivated by Lemma 8.7 of Popsescu's book) Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category. Let $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be a directed family of subobjects of $X$, where $I$ is a directed set. Then we have the following canonical isomorphism
> $$\text{Colim}_{I}X/X_i\cong X/(\sum_iX_i)=\inf_i X/X_i,$$
> provided that the colimits $\text{Colim}_{I}X_i$ and    $\text{Colim}_{I}X/X_i$ exists. Dually, let $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be a downward directed family of subobjects of $X$, where $I$ is a downward directed set. Then we have the following canonical isomorphism
> $$\text{Lim}_{I}X_i\cong \text{Ker} \sup_i(X/X_i)=\cap_i X_i$$
> provided that the limits $\text{Lim}_{I}X_i$ and    $\text{Lim}_{I}X/X_i$ exists.

**Proof.** Taking the colimits of the sequence $X_i\to X\to X/X_i$ indexed by the directed set $I$, we obtain the following exact sequence
$$\text{Colim}_{I} X_i\to X=\text{Colim}_{I}X\to\text{Colim}_{I}X/X_i\to 0.$$
The image of the $\text{Colim}_{I} X_i\to X$ is $\sum_{i}X_i$. Therefore we have the canonical isomorphism
$$\text{Colim}_{I}X/X_i\cong X/(\sum_iX_i).$$
The dual statement follows directly by considering in the opposite category. **QED.**

AB5* condition can only be characterized by the condition (directly dual to the condition in the question):

> For any small directed family $(Y_i)_{i\in I}$ of quotient objects of an object $Y$, there is a canonical isomorphism $\text{Lim}_{I^\text{op}}Y_i\cong \sup_iY_i.$